# Proof of the 'free index analysis' rule for the summation convention.

Tags: summation, tensors, classical-mechanics, convention

In Babak Majidzadeh Garjani's note *Summation Convention and Vector Algebra* ([link](http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/SummationConvention.pdf)), he seems to imply multiple times that whenever the 'free index analysis' rule is not violated, one can proceed safely. The notes contain no proof of this.

The idea of the analysis is similar to dimensional analysis in physics. The idea is that per example 
$$ a_{ij}(x_i+x_j) \neq a_{ij}x_i + a_{ij}y_j, $$
due to the fact that setting $z_{ij} = (x_i+x_j)$, we have on the left-hand-side $a_{ij}(x_i+x_j) = a_{ij}z_{ij}$ which is a 'term' (the author's terminology) that has no free indices while on the right-hand-side we have two terms but even the first of them, $a_{ij}x_i$, has $j$ as a free index. By this 'free index analysis', the equality cannot hold.

That is fine, but as I explained in the first paragraph, the author seems to imply that the converse is true: **Whenever the free index analysis holds, the manipulation is valid**. He uses this later in a manipulation such as 
$$ a_{ij}x_iy_j + a_{ji}x_iy_j = (a_{ij} + a{ji})\;x_iy_j. $$
This is an identity stated explicitly in *Schaum's outline of theory and problems of tensor calculus by David Kay*.

I was not able to find anywhere a proof of this identity. I think this is usually given as an exercise. But what would be more useful is a proof of the general principle in bold. Is it true? Is it treated in detail somewhere?

Comment: When you say he "seems to imply", the first thing I suspect is that you are overinterpreting his prose and he actually meant no such thing. He probably meant only that the expressions pass this test, so one cannot dismiss them immediately by it. However that only means that one must use a deeper analysis to confirm or deny their validity. Since you provided no examples of why you think otherwise, and I am not about to read a whole textbook to figure it out for you, that is the most I can say.

Comment: "He probably meant only that the expressions pass this test".
It does not look like it. by 'seems to imply' let me specifically quote:
"In the solution above, I have used the distributivity law to write aij xixj + aji xixj = (aij + aji)xixj, which in this case, by free index analysis rule, is valid."
But nowhere has he nailed that rule in the sense 'if rule does not break, then manipulation is valid'.

Irrespective of this reference, would you know of any other reference where the properties of such 'free index analysis' are proved? and whether the bold sentence in the post is true?

Comment: This "free index analysis" rule is - as far as I am aware - something of his own invention. That is, the name, statement and "algorithm" are something he put together. The basic Idea - that the free indices on both sides of an equation must be the same, is a well-known and obvious truth - provided the expression isn't constant with respect to the missing free indices on the other side (an exception to his rule which does occasionally occur). It is the distributive law that justifies the multiplication - provided it is done correctly. His rule just says he didn't make the most obvious errors.